# Requirements for beginner using twitter api to retweet specific tweets

Tags: api, twitter

I am new to twitter api.

I want to search tweets that have 2 specific terms and 1 specific hashtag, and then I want to retweet them in my account for the purpose of consolidating all the tweets.

Do I need to have a developer account?

Should I look to an already existing app (I prefer one that is free or open source), or can I do this with twitter api as a regular user?

Any tutorials or instructions are greatly appreciated. TIA.

I have applied for a developer account, but I don't know how long it will take - I also don't know what the criteria are for being granted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found different kinds of "retweet" applets on ifttt.com - I implemented one of them, and it accomplished what I wanted to achieve, though not perfectly, and there was no documentation to customize functionality, etc.

I couldn't find information anywhere about using twitter API without a developer account, so I applied for that type of account. They emailed approximately 3 times to get more information about my use case, and purposes, intent of use, what I intend to develop, etc. My application was approved within approximately 48 hours.

I will update this answer if there is more information I think might be valuable to share.